# How to play audio from server use expo-av in react-native

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

I try to play video from server. This is my code:

```
import React, {useState,  useEffect} from 'react';
import {  Button } from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

export default function App() {
  const [audioStatus, setAudioStatus] = useState(false)
  const [sound, setSound] = useState(new Audio.Sound());
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    (async () => {
            console.log('status', audioStatus)
            if (audioStatus) {
                await sound.loadAsync('https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3')
                try {
                    await sound.playAsync()
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            }else {
                await sound.stopAsync()
                await sound.unloadAsync()
            }
          })()
  },[audioStatus])
  
  return (
      <Button color={audioStatus ? 'red' : 'green'} title={'play'} onPress={()=>setAudioStatus(!audioStatus)} />
  );
}
```

And I get error:

```
 LOG  status false
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 15):
Error: Cannot complete operation because sound is not loaded.
http://192.168.100.60:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:100133:28
generatorResume@[native code]
asyncGeneratorStep@http://192.168.100.60:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:20982:26
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.